# Replace dynamic line in file

Tags: linux, sed

I am attempting to replace a line in a file that could vary on different machines.  For example the line could be like the following examples:

`testLine=14`
`testLine=320`
`testLine=abc`

Knowing that the lines are not the same every time I have attempted to use `sed` to replace the line, but the extra is appended at the end.  The command I would use is:

`sed -i 's/testLine=*/testLine=test/g' fileName`

This command would result in the above examples becoming:

`testLine=test14`
`testLine=test320`
`testLine=testabc`

I want these lines to only equal `testLine=test` and remove what existed to the right of the equals sign.  What do I need to add to the arguments that would produce the result I am seeking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add `.` before the `*`

```
sed -i 's/testLine=.*/testLine=test/' fileName
```

OR

```
sed -i 's/^testLine=.*/testLine=test/' fileName
```

Your regex `testLine=*` matches the string `testLine` plus the following `=` zero or more times. So it stops when it reaches `=` symbol. But `testLine=.*` would matches the string `testLine` plus the following zero or more characters. In your case, the above regex would replace the whole line with `testLine=test`

Comment: `g` is not needed in this case ;-)

Answer (score 0):

using awk

```
awk -F "=" '{if($1 == "testLine") printf("%s=test%s\n",$1,$2)}' file.txt > file.txt
```

outupt:

```
testLine=test14
testLine=test320
testLine=testabc
```

I have used -F "=" as input fiels , so $1 will before "=" and $2 is after "=", I have used printf to produce desired output